# Navbar toggler hides behind the images once screen collapses

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The toggle button is designed to function only for xs screens and all the nav links go to the toggle. But once I click on the toggle button, it comes with white background once and then all of a sudden collapses to the size of the navbar making the nav links merge with the content below the bar. you can see the images to understand it better. Please help!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
            <i class="navbar-toggler-icon"></i>
        </button>
        <a class="mr-auto navbar-brand nh myfont" href=".\index.html"> <img src="images/logo.png" width=6 0px height=7 0px> Sidhant Aggarwal</a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto nl">
                <li class="nav-item mrn"> <a class="nav-link" href="#about"> About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item mrn"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Resume</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item mrn"> <a class="nav-link" href=".\contactus.html"> Certifications</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-flex-icons flex-row">
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/"><i class = "fa fa-linkedin fa-xs"></i></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="mailto:"><i class = "fa fa-github fa-xs"></i></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="mailto:"><i class = "fa fa-envelope fa-xs"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[image: you can see how toggle is not displaying the nav links inside its background]

Comment: I found no mistake on your snippet, Please provide that type of snippet that shows your problem clearly

Answer (score 0):

Did you assign a background to the `navbar-nav`? You can assign a color to be sure about it

working snippet below:

```css
.restOfThePage {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.navbar-nav {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                <i class="navbar-toggler-icon"></i>
            </button>
    <a class="mr-auto navbar-brand nh myfont" href=".\index.html"> <img src="images/logo.png" width=6 0px height=7 0px> Sidhant Aggarwal</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto nl">
        <li class="nav-item mrn"> <a class="nav-link" href="#about"> About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mrn"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Resume</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mrn"> <a class="nav-link" href=".\contactus.html"> Certifications</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-flex-icons flex-row">
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/"><i class = "fa fa-linkedin fa-xs"></i></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="mailto:"><i class = "fa fa-github fa-xs"></i></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="mailto:"><i class = "fa fa-envelope fa-xs"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class='restOfThePage'>
  <h1>Other content</h1>
  <p>What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
    with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using
    Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default
    model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Where does it come from? Contrary
    to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of
    the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et
    Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by
    English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Where can I get some? There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't
    look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as
    necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore
    always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: didn't change anything

Comment: Remove the background color in my snippet and you’ll see your case being replicated...